# Why superpositions?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, measurement-problem, double-slit-experiment, superposition, wavefunction-collapse

I've seen a lot of stuff on superpositions, namely the double slit experiment. And every video I watch, it tells me the same thing:

> *It's amazing that when these particles are being observed they behave differently than when they are not being observed.*

But why? Can anyone tell me why superpositions happen? And why are they based on observation?

Comment: Hi, there are many interpretations about `the wave function collapse`. Maybe the [link to wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_function_collapse#History_and_context) will be helpful.

Comment: It is quite difficult to make out what you are really asking here. The block quote really seems to indicate you are asking about the wavefunction collapse & calling that _superposition_ (as perhaps @EdenHarder mentioned above). But "_Can anyone tell me why superpositions happen_" means something else to most of us. Superpositions are a natural part of linear systems, i.e. when the underlying theory is linear, the net effect of multiple sources can be assessed using the superposition principle. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: It is a common misconception to think that nature behaves differently when it is "being observed". Nature does not know what an observation is, neither does it care. "Observation" is an artificial distinction made by humans. When you remove a detector from a quantum mechanical experiment, it's simply not the same experiment, even though many people seem to  think that it should be, because for a classical system the existence of that detector wouldn't matter. So what does that mean? It only means that many people are uncomfortable with nature not being classical.

Comment: If anyone can answer this question, he/she will win the Nobel Prize. This is the question on quantum mechanics. Things change when it gets smaller. People are trying to figure out why there is wave-particle duality. Observation is central in quantum mechanics. Observation plays a role, but in our everyday world, observation is nothing special. If you see a moon, you see a moon. If you don't see a moon, the moon is still there, but in the quantum world, the moon is everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

If we take two slits large enough for bowling balls and with a much smaller than the ball separation ,  and a pile of bowling balls and design a catapult throwing the balls at the slits parallel to the ground within the window covering the two slits, what will happen?

1) some balls will pass through one of the slits without touching, straight ahead

2)some will hit the interface between the two slits

3) some may hit the slit sides an acquire a lateral momentum from the scatter.

Suppose the balls squirt ink hitting a wall behind the slits, what shall we see?

A superposition of blobs indicating where the ball hit.

So superpositions happen macroscopically any way. We can interpret the ink blots with classical mechanics of the trajectories and we expect blob shadows of the two slits plus fainter outlying blots for the ones scattered at the lip of the slit.

When we use electrons and the slits are separated by a distance comparable to the quantum [mechanical wavelength](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matter_wave) of the electron  we are shooting at the slits, this is the superposition we observe when we send a single electron at a time at [the two slits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment):

[image: double slit]

> Electron buildup over time

The top screen has very few hits, and it looks random (the slits are in the middle location as far as the screen goes).  Not a good expectation if we thought the electron followed classical mechanics as bowling balls do. Note this is a centered beam line the electrons are following.

As more and more hits are superposed we see an interference pattern emerge in the statistical superposition of hits.

This superposition cannot be explained with classical mechanics. We have interpreted with quantum mechanics which is a mathematical model with postulates that connect observations to the mathematics . For interpreting this case it is the [Born rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Born_rule) that is important

> The Born rule states that if an observable corresponding to a Hermitian operator A with discrete spectrum is measured in a system with normalized wave function , then [image: psi]
>
> - the measured result will be one of the eigenvalues [image: \lambda] of A, and
> - the probability of measuring a given eigenvalue [image: \lambda_i] will equal [image: psipsi]  where [image: P_i] is the projection onto the eigenspace of A corresponding to [image: \lambda_i].

This is a trite comment

> It's amazing that when these particles are being observed they behave differently than when they are not being observed.

If something is not observed one cannot know what it is doing, either classically or quantum mechanically. What one knows are the results of the experiments, and this particularly shows that the electron, a point particle in the [standard model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model) , leaves a measurement on the  screen (x,y). This (x,y) are the operators to put in the Born rule. The accumulation on the screen gives a probability for being located at that (x,y).

Note that the accumulation of the blots in the classical bowling ball experiment also give a probability distribution. But there we have classical mechanics and can calculate the underlying mechanism. In the particle framework quantum mechanics only calculates probabilities for us. There is no underlying classical behavior. This is dramatically seen by the interference in the probability distribution generated experimentally, which gives the quantum mechanical wavelength for the electrons impinging on the screen.

Comment: I don't understand your bowling ball analogy, or gedanken experiment. Why do you say a "superposition of blobs" occurs? Will you get something different than two bands of blobs corresponding to the two slits?

Comment: @JohnFistere if the classical probability of the bowling balls to hit an edge is zero ( the balls much smaller than the slit dimension, then an image of the two slits will appear for perpendicular to the plane of the slits throws) then no superposition. I am looking when the balls can pass the slits but can also hit the edges and be deflected. Then there will be a widening of the image from the deflected hits which will overlay each other in the image, between the two slits

Comment: if you are simply saying that some balls will hit the edge of the slit and therefore the image of that slit will be wider, I agree. But it is not an example of superposition. I also thought you were saying that with two slits an interference pattern of bowling ball impacts would appear, and I am sure that is not true.

Comment: @JohnFistere superposition means one on top of the other. Interference is not expected to exist for classical balls, and it would have been seen. That is why quantum mechanics is needed for particle sizes, because instead of simple superposition, interference patterns emerge for particles

Answer (score 0):

Things are amazing for as long as you do not (or refuse to) understand them! What happens is that, counterintuitively, everything around us is waves (matter or de Broglie waves). Hence they naturally interfere, producing for example the diffraction patterns behind a double slit (or indeed even a single slit). Waves naturally and unsurprisingly obey the superposition principle.

Observing such waves in a which-way experiment means strongly interacting with the wave. That scrambles its phase, destroying interference.